# When doing service mysql restart on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 getting error: No directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: mysql, directory, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

*All of this done in root already

Tried initially doing:
`mkdir /home/omid`
Got back:
`mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/omid' : File exists`

Tried to make the directory a different way:
`mkhomedir_helper omid`
Nothing happened afterwards.

I checked if /home exists which it was able to cd. 
`cd /home/omid`

Tried to change the CREATE_HOME to yes in /etc/login.defs 
It didn't even have CREATE_HOME in there but I added it then ended up deleting it after.

Not really sure where to go from here to be honest, I also tried changing the owner and groups but still nothing.